# Argparse: two positional arguments with nargs='+'

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to do mathematical operations between images. I have defined (simplified version of my real code):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Arithmetic operations on images')
parser.add_argument("input1", metavar='input1', action='store',
      help='list of input images to operate with', nargs="+", type=str)
parser.add_argument("operation", metavar='operation', action='store', type=str, 
      help='type of operation (+,-,*,/) to be done', nargs=1)
parser.add_argument("input2",metavar='input2', action='store', nargs="+", 
      type=str, help='image (or value) with which to perform the operation on input1')
```

This code, produces:

```
arith.py -h
usage: arith.py [-h] input1 [input1 ...] operation input2 [input2 ...]
```

so it does understand that input1 could contain one or more elements, operation will be a single one, and input2 could be any number of elements.

The problem, of course, is that having two positional arguments with an undetermined number of elements, argparse confuses what is what. I have tried adding choices=["+", "-", "*", "/"] to 'operation', so that it would know where to do the separation, but it seems argparse is not able to do it. Actually, in the argparse documentation, talking about nargs='*' you can read:

> Note that it generally doesn’t make much sense to have more than one positional argument with nargs='*'

I have thought that I could add together args.input1, args.operation and args.input2 and separate myself looking for "+", "-", "/", "*", but before doing something so ugly I thought about tapping the collective mind.

Comment: I'm not sure `argparse` is suitable for what you're doing here. It would probably be easier just to go through `sys.argv` directly.

Comment: Hi khelwood. Actually, I parse the sys.argv using argparse. This gives me  the help for the user "for free", and it does all the checking types and existing variables for me. Doing directly sys.argv would be like my solution of pooling together input1, operation and input2 and then separating myself. Doable, but ugly ;). Thanks anyway!

Comment: `argparse` can construct such a help message, but that doesn't mean it can actually parse arguments the way you want. If I called `arith.py a b c d e f g`, which one is `operation`? It could be any of `b` through `f`. `argparse` doesn't have any kind of back-tracking pattern matcher built-in; it just processes arguments from left to right in a greedy fashion.

Comment: There may be a clearer way to structure the arguments. How are `input1` and `input2` processed? Does the `k`th element of `input1` get paired with the `k`th element of `input2` using the specified operator? Or do you compute a Cartesian product of the two lists and apply the operator to each element of the product? Or something else?

Comment: If len(input1) = len(input2) they get paired. If len(input2) = 1 the operation is done to all the elements of input1 with that single element of input2.

Answer (score 2):

When allocating strings to positionals, the parser only distinguishes between ones that start with a prefix char (e.g. '-') and the rest.  It cannot distinguish between strings that represent 'numbers' and ones that represent 'operations'.  In effect it performs this regex operation:

```
re.match('(A+)(A)(A+)','AAAAAAAAA')
```

which would produce `(AAAAAA),(A),(A)`.  It allocates enough strings to the the last 2 groups to satisfy their specs, and allocates the rest to the first.

So you need some sort of 'flag' to mark the end of the first list.

This is, I think, the closest you'll get with `argparse`:

```
parser.add_argument("input1", nargs="+", type=int)
parser.add_argument("-o", "--operation", choices=['+','minus','*','/'] )
parser.add_argument("input2", nargs="+", type=int)
```

which should turn

```
PROG 1 3 4 -o + 5 6 7
PROG 1 3 4 -o+ 5 6 7
PROG 1 3 4 --operation=+ 5 6 7
```

into (I think)

```
namespace(input1=[1,3,4], operation='+', input2=[5,6,7])
```

Notice that the list of `choices` does not include '-'.  That's because the parser treats that as a prefix_char.  There may be a way of sneaking it in as an argument value, but I'm not going to take the time to find it.

I converted the `input1` values to integers in the parser.  You could do that after.  And of course make the floats instead.

I omitted default parameters like `type=str`, `action='store'`.

---

But perhaps a better solution is to take all the values as 1 list, and split it up yourself.  At least with these 3 arguments you aren't making much use of `argparse` power.

```
alist = ['1','2','3','+','4','5','6']
i = <find index of '+-/*'>
input1 = alist[:i]
operations = alist[i]
input2 = alsits[i+1:]
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. In the past, the only way I have been able to sneak a "-" into a non-positional argument is:

-o " -"

so a string with a space before, so that the - is taken as a part of a string

Comment: Specifying something else like `#` as the prefix_char, might freeup `-` for use as an argument.

Comment: Yes, hpaulj, that's the approach I followed, as I hinted in the OP. It seems I was asking for too much. I just left the three arguments, though, for clarity to the users. After parsing I joined them up again and split them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you used "required optional" arguments you could make this work. If would require options on the command line to show when changing from left operands to the operation to changing to the right operands. eg.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument("--left-operands", "-l", nargs="+", required=True)
parser.add_argument("--right-operands", "-r", nargs="+", required=True)
parser.add_argument("--operation", "-o", choices=["+", "-", "*", "/"], required=True)

argline = "-l 1 2 -o + -r 3 4"

print(parser.parse_args(argline.split(" ")))
```

Comment: Thanks, Dunes, but not exactly what I was looking for. I want the arguments to be positional.  Otherwise, I will go back to the idea of putting input1, input2, and operation together and separating them internally.